# How can I share Hibernate TypeDefs and GenericGenerator definitions between projects?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two projects, `upstream` and `downstream`. `upstream` is a compile-time dependency of `downstream`.

I have a class, `BaseEntity`, in `upstream`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T extends Serializable> {
    public abstract T getId()

    ...
```

I also have a `CustomUUIDGenerator` class in `upstream`:

```
public class CustomUUIDGenerator extends UUIDGenerator {
    @Override
    public Serializable Generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        ...
```

I have a derived class of `UserType`, `JsonbType`, in `upstream` as well.

I have added these annotations to the `package-info.java` file in the root package of `upstream`:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUIDGenerator", strategy="<path>.CustomUUIDGenerator")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonbType.class)
```

In `downstream`, I have a class `TestEntity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity extends BaseEntity<UUID> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private TestPojo data;

    public static class TestPojo {
        String prop1;
        String prop2;

        <constructors for TestPojo omitted, but they are in my code>
    }

    <getters and setters omitted>
}
```

I have a test in `downstream` that tries to persist a `TestEntity`, but when I run it, I see `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: UUIDGenerator`. If I remove the `generator` parameter from `@GeneratedValue` in `TestEntity` and run it, I see `org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [jsonb]`.

What are the conditions for these 'definition'-type annotations being available to a class? If I want `@Type(type = "jsonb")` to work for all entities in projects that have `upstream` as a dependency, how would I accomplish that?